# How to identify sub sets of an object?

Tags: clojure, iterator, combinatorics

How would I best iterate over the below object in Clojure?

```
{
  :item-set-1 ["a" "b" "c"]
  :item-set-2 ["d" "e" "f"]
}
```

I want to try and identify all sub sets of the object and produce a result like this:

```
{
 [:item-set-1 ["a"]]
 [:item-set-1 ["a" "b"]]
 [:item-set-1 ["a" "b" "c"]]
 [:item-set-1 ["b"]]
 [:item-set-1 ["b" "c"]]
 [:item-set-1 ["c"]]
 [:item-set-2 ["d"]]
 [:item-set-2 ["d" "e"]]
 [:item-set-2 ["d" "e" "f"]]
 [:item-set-1 ["e"]]
 [:item-set-1 ["e" "f"]]
 [:item-set-1 ["f"]]

 [:item-set-1 ["a"] [:item-set-2 ["d"]]]
 [:item-set-1 ["b"] [:item-set-2 ["e"]]]
 [:item-set-1 ["c"] [:item-set-2 ["f"]]]

 [:item-set-1 ["a" "b"] [:item-set-2 ["d" "e"]]]
 [:item-set-1 ["a" "b"] [:item-set-2 ["e" "f"]]]
 [:item-set-1 ["a" "b"] [:item-set-2 ["d" "f"]]]
 [:item-set-1 ["b" "c"] [:item-set-2 ["d" "e"]]]
 [:item-set-1 ["b" "c"] [:item-set-2 ["e" "f"]]]
 [:item-set-1 ["b" "c"] [:item-set-2 ["d" "f"]]]
 [:item-set-1 ["a" "c"] [:item-set-2 ["d" "e"]]]
 [:item-set-1 ["a" "c"] [:item-set-2 ["e" "f"]]]
 [:item-set-1 ["a" "c"] [:item-set-2 ["d" "f"]]]

 [:item-set-1 ["a" "b" "c"] [:item-set-2 ["d" "e" "f"]]]
}
```

I belive I can use `clojure.math.combinatorics` to identify the subsets in each key but not the whole object.

Update: 
I attempted to produce the sub sets with this code:

```
(defn generate-freq-item-set []
  (let [result [{:data (generate-string {:item-set-1 ["a" "b" "c"] :item-set-2 ["d" "e" "f"]})}]
        items (as-> () items
                    (->> (for [row result]
                           (for [data (parse-string (:data row))]
                              (for [subset (combo/subsets (second data))]
                               (conj items {(first data) subset}))))))
        frequencies (sort-by last >
                             (->> (apply concat (apply concat (apply concat items)))
                                      (frequencies)))]
      (prn frequencies)))
```

But this produces the following output which is not exactly what I'm after:

```
([{"item-set-1" ()} 1] 
 [{"item-set-2" ("d")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-1" ("a" "b" "c")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-2" ("d" "e")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-1" ("b" "c")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-2" ("d" "e" "f")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-2" ()} 1] 
 [{"item-set-1" ("a" "b")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-1" ("c")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-2" ("e")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-2" ("d" "f")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-2" ("f")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-2" ("e" "f")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-1" ("b")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-1" ("a")} 1] 
 [{"item-set-1" ("a" "c")} 1])
```

Comment: uh... Do I understand it correctly that "result like this" you've sent contains only parts of the result, not the whole? E.g. `[:item-set-1 ["a" "c"] [:item-set-2 ["d" "f"]]]` is missing...

Comment: @netchkin I missed that in my example. I have updated the question.

Comment: what about length = 1 ? doesn't it have to contain also pairs for ["a"] ["e"], ["a"] ["f"] etc?

Comment: all sub sets - I think it also means e.g. [:item-set-1 ["c"] [:item-set-2 ["d" "e"]]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach this problem as follows.

At first, I'd splice initial map you have into a list, saving in the metadata the info about the set where the item belonged to.

Since it is not possible to attach metadata to raw strings, we need to create a wrapper type:

```
(defrecord ItemSetElement [x])

(defn make-item-set-element [x]
  (->ItemSetElement x))

(defn unwrap-item-set-element [elem]
  (:x elem))
```

Then go the functions that convert an initial map to sequence, saving needed info:

```
(defn wrap-element-and-save-owner [owner s]
  (with-meta (make-item-set-element s) {::owner owner}))

(defn prepare-data [data]
  (mapcat
   (fn [[key ss]]
     (map (partial wrap-element-and-save-owner key) ss))
   data))

> (prepare-data {:item-set-1 ["a" "b"], :item-set-2 ["c"]})
({:x "a"} {:x "b"} {:x "c"})
```

As you see, the result of `prepare-data` is just a sequence, but every element of the sequence has information about the "owner" set in its meta, e.g.:

```
> (meta (first (prepare-data {:item-set-1 ["a" "b"], :item-set-2 ["c"]})))
{:user/owner :item-set-1}
```

Having a sequence, we can use `clojure.math.combinatorics/subsets` to generate all its subsets:

```
> (require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as combo])
nil
> (combo/subsets (prepare-data {:item-set-1 ["a" "b"], :item-set-2 ["c"]}))
(()
 ({:x "a"})
 ({:x "b"})
 ({:x "c"})
 ({:x "a"} {:x "b"})
 ({:x "a"} {:x "c"})
 ({:x "b"} {:x "c"})
 ({:x "a"} {:x "b"} {:x "c"}))
```

Each element of the subset still has information about its "owner", so we can easily convert it to an initial-like structure. Here's a function for that:

```
(defn reconstruct-item-sets [subset]
  (->> subset
       (group-by #(::owner (meta %)))
       (map (fn [[key elements]]
              [key (map unwrap-item-set-element elements)]))
       (into {})))
```

To sum up here's all the code including function, that glues everything together:

```
(require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as combo])

(defrecord ItemSetElement [x])

(defn make-item-set-element [x]
  (->ItemSetElement x))

(defn unwrap-item-set-element [elem]
  (:x elem))

(defn wrap-element-and-save-owner [owner s]
  (with-meta (make-item-set-element s) {::owner owner}))

(defn prepare-data [data]
  (mapcat
   (fn [[key ss]]
     (map (partial wrap-element-and-save-owner key) ss))
   data))

(defn reconstruct-item-sets [subset]
  (->> subset
       (group-by #(::owner (meta %)))
       (map (fn [[key elements]]
              [key (map unwrap-item-set-element elements)]))
       (into {})))

 (defn my-subsets [data]
   (->> data
        prepare-data
        combo/subsets
        (map reconstruct-item-sets)))

(def data {:item-set-1 ["a" "b"]
           :item-set-2 ["c" "d" "e"]})

> (my-subsets data)
({}
 {:item-set-1 ("a")}
 {:item-set-1 ("b")}
 {:item-set-2 ("c")}
 {:item-set-2 ("d")}
 {:item-set-2 ("e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a" "b")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a"), :item-set-2 ("c")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a"), :item-set-2 ("d")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a"), :item-set-2 ("e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("b"), :item-set-2 ("c")}
 {:item-set-1 ("b"), :item-set-2 ("d")}
 {:item-set-1 ("b"), :item-set-2 ("e")}
 {:item-set-2 ("c" "d")}
 {:item-set-2 ("c" "e")}
 {:item-set-2 ("d" "e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a" "b"), :item-set-2 ("c")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a" "b"), :item-set-2 ("d")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a" "b"), :item-set-2 ("e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a"), :item-set-2 ("c" "d")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a"), :item-set-2 ("c" "e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a"), :item-set-2 ("d" "e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("b"), :item-set-2 ("c" "d")}
 {:item-set-1 ("b"), :item-set-2 ("c" "e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("b"), :item-set-2 ("d" "e")}
 {:item-set-2 ("c" "d" "e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a" "b"), :item-set-2 ("c" "d")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a" "b"), :item-set-2 ("c" "e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a" "b"), :item-set-2 ("d" "e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a"), :item-set-2 ("c" "d" "e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("b"), :item-set-2 ("c" "d" "e")}
 {:item-set-1 ("a" "b"), :item-set-2 ("c" "d" "e")})
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detail answer!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have clojure installed now, but in essense, you need to do it like this:
1) map subset function to each itemset. You will end up with two sets with all the subsets.
2) apply cartesian-product to these two sets of subsets. That's it. Cartesian product takes two sets and outputs all possible combinations.

I'll get back to you once I'm back from work and have clojure installed

---

EDIT

finally got home, here's the code:

```
(require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as combo])

(def inputdata {:item-set-1 ["a" "b" "c"] :item-set-2 ["d" "e" "f"]})

(defn subsets-without-empty [set] (filter not-empty (combo/subsets set)))

(defn to-subset-maps [kv] 
  (map (fn [v] {(key kv) v})
  (subsets-without-empty (val kv))))

(defn create-subsets [dictOfSets] (map to-subset-maps dictOfSets))

(apply combo/cartesian-product (create-subsets inputdata))
```

`subsets-without-empty` gets you all subsets excluding empty one, as you suggested

`to-subset-maps` converts `{:a [1 2]}` into `[{:a [1]} {:a [2]} {:a [1 2]}]`, i.e. creates subsets and propagates the original key to each subset (required by your output format)

`create-subsets` just applies the `to-subset-maps` for each member of the input map.

Finally, we have the results in a collection. So we just need to unwrap it and pass to `cartesian-product` to get all the combinations, that's where the last line with `apply` comes in. Now, this solution works for any number of dimensions (or keys in the input map).